# Missing hours in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a weather data in Excel taken every hour for 2008. Year of 2008 had 366 days thus 8784 hours. However, I noticed that there are 8767 rows and therefore 8784 - 8767 = 17 hours are missing. Unfortunately, I don't know which hours are missing throughout the whole year. I also have an extra column which displays the date along with the time in the format of "day-month-year time". E.g. 31-12-08 23:00.

Is there any method in Excel so the missing hours can be added as an extra row?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simply subtract one datetime from the previous one, if the answer is not 1 hour - then you know where the missing rows are. You can use a simple IF function for this, e.g.

```
=IF(HOUR(A2)-HOUR(A1)=1,"","Missing")
```

Of course, you need to copy this formula down a column so that it checks all the rows.

[image]

Comment: When I subtract A2-A1 it gives me the answer of 0.04667. SO instead of 1 I use IF(A3-A2=0.041667,"","Missing"). But nothing happens.

Comment: You can use the HOUR function to just compare hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert rows using a **VBA** macro, but there is an easier way without macros.  Start a brand new worksheet.  In **A1** enter:

```
=DATE(2008,1,1)+TIME(0,0,0)
```

In **A2** enter:

```
=A1+TIME(1,0,0)
```

and copy down.  With proper formatting this will look ike:

[image: pic]

This will be a complete set of date/times.  At this point you can pick-up data from your original worksheet using *VLOOKUP()* or *MATCH() / INDEX()*

This will also allow you to identify the missing rows.